# Blazor Server app Loads and remove JS scripts

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor

I am developing a Blazor app which used Chart.Js Library. When the project is started the Chart Loads and disappers immediately.

But when i set Render-mood of my app to static, the Chart.JS file loaded stays without disappearing.

from my oservation, having **framework/blazor.server.js** removes other pure JS.

When i use Rendrer-mood as staticm the JSInterop runtime to call pure JS in blazor does not work. How do i solve this pls?

Comment: Please add configuration files.